# Chinese or Japanese animation with running white horse at the end

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

25+ (or even 30+) years ago I saw an animation on TV. I would really love to watch it again, to finally understand what I already watched twice as a child.

I only remember the following:

1. It took a long time. Not as short as a Tom & Jerry short animation. Pretty much like a full sized movie.
2. I liked it, even though I did not understand anything of what they said (I might have seen it on a foreign channel).
3. It was Chinese or Japanese, most likely. The kind of graphics leads me to that conclusion.
4. I always believed that it represented the story of a fairy tale or of a legend. What was the actual story is what drives my curiosity now.
5. I can only remember the following scene, at the end of the film: a beautiful white horse was running on some white natural scenery (fields, mountains...).
6. It is possible that the horse was running allegorically through the air, the scenery was there as a background. Or through the afterlife world as well - this scene made me feel like there was some death involved..
7. I associate the image of a girl to the running horse scene. Maybe the girl was somehow related to the horse in the movie, and they just parted at the end.
8. The horse was running on the screen from my right-hand towards my left-hand. I am quite sure about it.
9. The hair on the back of the neck of the horse was long and magnificent, waving (?) in the wind as he ran.
10. The horse was quite likely to be male.
11. I do not remember the horse to have had a horn on the forehead, or anywhere (so, most likely, not unicorn).
12. In the last scenes there was only one girl, not two or more people. (if I am not wrong).
13. The people looked more like Chinese / Japanese (or, generically, Asian), rather than European. Definitely not African or Inuits. Maybe closer to the truth: the way that people appear in Asian animations - but regular face and body characteristics - I mean, no big round mouths far on the cheek, under the ear.

Note: our TV at that time was B&W, so the white might have been not so white on a color TV. However, it was not anything dark enough to suggest other colors.

Another note: I cannot be at all sure that it was anime or manga, that is why I prefer to ask here.

Comment: Since you mention Tom& Jerry I want to ask this is not a single episode right?

Comment: As far as I remember, it was a stand-alone movie. I used the Tom & Jerry as an alternate measurement for "about 10-20-30 min".

Comment: Could it have been the Last Unicorn? Not strictly a horse, I know.

Comment: @Showsni: Do you suggest that I remember the horse and I do not remember the horn? :D That might actually be true. And The Last Unicorn has a surprisingly similar ending. I edit the answer with some details - thanks for helping me clarify some details in my mind.

Comment: @Showsni: According to the preview I made on youtube, The Last Unicorn seems to be worth seeing too. Also, I remember quite clearly the white-on-white image.

Comment: Last Unicorn was my first thought too. Seen by me as a child too, but not being understand at this time...

Answer (score 5):

"The Last Unicorn" 's ending fits and so does the timeline (it came out in 1982).

If you want from right to left running with some white background, it is previously in the movie (The song is "Man's road")

(The other option I see as a possibility is Thowra, ["The Silver Brumby"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Brumby), which is a cartoon that ran from 29 October 1994 – 17 September 1998. See at 53 minute mark for snow scenes.

)

It doesn't sound like "The Prince and the White Horse", which came out in 2000. Too short and the ending doesn't fit.

Comment: Anything from 2000 is too new. But thanks for the tip. I will try to find that one too. The graphics of "The prince and the White Horse" looks "Asian", so it is definitely closer to what I remember.

Answer (score 4):

Your description reminds me of [*Gasaraki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasaraki) (1998). The ending had Japanese imagery, a girl and a white horse running from right to left.

It's an anime made in the late 90's so barely in your time frame

[image]